# metodo post de angular quitar caracter +

Tags: angular4

nose muy bien lo que está pasando, pero cuando envio un formulario con angular a la API que tengo para que lo introduzca a la base de datos si le pongo en algún string el caracter '+' lo cambia por un espacio.

```
 //Metodo para crear la vivienda
 crearVivienda(vivienda : Vivienda): Promise<any>{
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

var body = "UR="+vivienda.UR+"&num_promocion="+vivienda.num_promocion+"&Direccion="+vivienda.direccion+";

console.log(body);

return this.http.post(viviendasURLcreate, body, options)
  .toPromise()
  .then()
  .catch(this.handleError);

}
```

He probado en enviar el formulario por postman y lo introduce bien. Como tendría que hacer la petición para que no intercambie el caracter '+' por un espacio ' '

Gracias

Comment: Lo he resulto controlandolo en el servidor web, cambiando lo espacios por +  pero lo no se es como se debería hacer para que se controle desde angular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto suele ser un problema común y suele resultar muy raro al principio, ya que el `+` es usado por la URL para separar dos palabras. Para poder usarlo como tal, debes codificar los valores antes de agregarlos a la URL. En JS y TypeScript existe `encodeURI()`

Asi es como usas `encodeURI()` :

```
let encodedName = encodeURI('xyz+axis');
let encodedURI = 'http://localhost:3000/page?name='+encodedName;

//.. O también con string interpolation
let encodedURI = `http://localhost:3000/page?name=${ encodedName }`;
```

De la misma forma podrías decodificarlo, si fuerce necesario.

```
let decodedVar = decodeURI(encodedVar);
```

*Adicional:*

> Mas información en sobre codificación en [W3SChools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)